# Decoding with html_entity_decode, and then having problem with &nbsp;

Tags: php

After decoding the special character `&nbsp;` with the html_entity_decode function, I get spaces in replace of `&nbsp;` entities. My problem is when I check if `if ($decoded_str[5] == ' ')` it isn't true, though in `$decoded_str[5]` there is a space that was `&nbsp;` before decoding. How to settle the matter? I need to be able to check it like this way: `if ($decoded_str[5] == ' ')`

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense... How did we get an array out of the html_entity_decode function???

Comment: which array do you mean?

Comment: The way you talk about it, `$decoded_str[5]` is a string that contains a space in it, not a single space. So saying `$decoded_str[5] == ' '` would always return false because the string is not a single space, correct?

Comment: @animuson: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

Comment: Sorry, I was just confused with how he was talking about it, like it was an array of strings and that particular variable was more than one character.

Answer (score 4):

nbsp has a character code of 0xA0, and the space is 0x20.

Depending on your encoding, you may need to compare (ISO-8859-1 / default)

```
if ($decoded_str[5] === '\xa0')
```

or (UTF-8)

```
if ($decoded_str[5] === '\xc2' && $decoded_str[6] === '\xa0')
```

---

From the manual of [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

> **Note:** You might wonder why `trim(html_entity_decode('&nbsp;'));` doesn't reduce the string to an empty string, that's because the `'&nbsp;'` entity is not ASCII code 32 (which is stripped by `trim()`) but ASCII code 160 (0xa0) in the default ISO 8859-1 characterset.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `&nbsp;` is not a *space* : it's a [Non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nbsp).

This means its character code is not `0x20`, but `0xA0` *(well, of course, this depends on the charset, I suppose...)*

Comment: @Kenny > ergh ; one typo in a post, and it's just where it must not be ;-( thanks for the comment : I've corrected that :-)

Answer (score 0):

it's the right behaviour, because `html_entity_decode` converts all applicable html characters, so also & so you could check the space using this if..

```
if (htmlentities($dec) == '&nbsp;')
```

which is basically the comparison with the original value of the string...